# Почему нет запятой перед уточняющим оборотом?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, уточнения

"Наш аил расположен в предгорьях на широком плато, куда сбегаются из ущелий шумливые горные речки".

Структура, аналогичная этому предложению: "Я сидел в гостиной, на среднем диване". Тогда в чём разница?

Comment: Если вам понятен ответ, то вы можете проголосовать за него (стрелочка вверх), а также принять его (галочка).  Так на сайте принять благодарить участников, которые отвечают вам. Также можно задать дополнительные вопросы.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как в первом, так и во втором предложении возможны два варианта пунктуации. Всё зависит от того, является ли второе обстоятельство уточнением или нет. А уже от этого (вкладываемого смысла и контекста) будет зависеть интонация – логические ударения и паузы.

*Наш аил расположен в предгорьях на широком плат**О**, куда сбегаются из ущелий шумливые горные речки.*  В этом случае факт расположения аила в предгорьях не основная информация, акцент смещается на ***широкое плато***. Между обстоятельствами нет паузы.

*Наш аил расположен в предг**О**рьях, на широком плат**О**, куда сбегаются из ущелий шумливые горные речки.* Здесь главным обстоятельством являются ***предгорья***, а далее идёт уточнение (где именно). Есть пауза.

*Я сидел в гост**И**ной, на среднем див**А**не.* Аналогично предыдущему случаю.

*Я сидел в гостиной на среднем див**А**не.* Главная информация – диван. Или так: *Я сидел в гостиной на ср**Е**днем диване.*

> В зависимости от смысла одни и те же слова могут рассматриваться или не рассматриваться как уточняющее обстоятельство. Ср.:
> ***Впереди на дороге** толпились люди* (т. е. в передней части дороги). — *Впереди, **на дороге,** толпились люди* (т. е. сама дорога находилась впереди);
> ***Далеко в лесу** раздавались удары топора* (слушатель находится в лесу). — *Далеко, **в лесу,** раздавались удары топора* (слушатель находится вне леса)...

Источник: [**Уточняющие члены предложения**](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=118) (справочник Розенталя).

P. S. Кстати, на сайте [ЛИТМИР](https://www.litmir.me/br/?b=960&p=1) и не только предложение выглядит так: *Наш аил Куркуреу расположен в предгорьях на широком плато, куда сбегаются из многих ущелий шумливые горные речки* (Чингиз Айтматов, «Первый учитель»).

Comment: Спасибо, Александр, за ответ. Часто приходится сталкиваться с этой темой, но и для меня подобранный вами материал оказался очень ИНТЕРЕСНЫМ. Я выделила в нем три момента: 1. Авторский выбор основной и уточняющей информации. 2. Смысловой акцент (прорисовка пространства в тексте). 3. Учебный пример по Розенталю (обычно в авторском тексте прорисовка пространства известна). В таком виде перенесла материал на сайт. Как вы думаете, это соответствует действительности?

Comment: @Sharon Спасибо, Sharon! Думаю, что всё так. И всё соответствует. :) //  Где же автор вопроса?..

Comment: Самое неприятное, что такие спорные предложения часто добавляют в тесты, и ты чувствуешь себя не на экзамене по русскому языку, а на экзамене по выявлению экстрасенсорных способностей. То есть, ты должен не использовать правило, а угадать, какой из двух вариантов написания подразумевал составитель теста. Реально раздражает. Причём выдирают предложения из классики, не оставляя никакого контекста.

Comment: @ThePracticeOfChaos  Да, составители тестов в таких случаях, можно сказать, халатно относятся к своей работе (это не раз здесь обсуждалось).  А нашу работу Вы так и не хотите отметить стрелочками и галочками? :)

Answer (score 2):

**1.  Вместо вступления**

**Экстрасенсорные способности** – это хорошо сказано!  Другими словами, это внутреннее **чувство языка**.  В устной речи – мы все настоящие **маги**. Пусть даже она не всегда нормативна, но какая яркая и выразительная!

**А вот с письмом** у нас проблемы.  В то же время система русского правописания в своей основе безупречна, ведь ее (по большому счету)  300 лет академики составляли.  Но **эффективно пользоваться** этой системой мало кто умеет – не учат этому в школе.

**2. Кто виноват – в этом сложно разобраться, а что делать?**

Знаки **в тестах** можно ставить **по слуху**, а именно по структуре предложения и расстановке пауз и  ударений.  Даже если вы никогда не делали этого раньше, попробуйте включить интуицию. Или хотя бы проверьте свой предполагаемый ответ на слух. Просто прочитайте предложение и послушайте, как оно звучит.

Рассмотрим все это на примере.

Пример 1.  "***Наш аил расположен в предгорьях на широком платО, // куда сбегаются из ущелий шумливые горные рЕчки***".

Структура (по смыслу и по объему) явно **двухчастная**, дробить ее на три фразы не имеет смысла. Также вспомним, что правила допускают оба варианта (уточняющие и неоднородные обстоятельства, это авторский выбор). Поэтому **уточнение** в сложном предложении обозначать не будем.

Кстати, при обособлении второго обстоятельства возникают и **грамматические проблемы**: получается, что к "вставочному" обособленном члену мы относим **придаточное определительное** предложение, что не есть хорошо. Поэтому "обстоятельственная координата" должна быть единой. Так что при должной наблюдательности **подсказок для решения** достаточно.

Пример 2. ***Я сидел в гостиной, на среднем диване.***
Если не обозначить паузой уточнение, то предложение выглядит незаконченным. И еще не вполне логичным. Два обстоятельства как-то плохо объединяются друг с другом, если фраза уже закончена, так что отношения здесь именно уточняющие.

Сравнить:

(1) *Я сидел в гостИной, на среднем дивАне.* *Остальные гости расположились  на креслах и стульях.*  Автор описывает пространство.

(2) *Я сидел в гостиной на среднем дивАне, а дамы в креслах расположились напротив.* Сложное предложение со значением сопоставления (союз А) также удобнее делить на две части, поэтому **уточнение не обозначаем**.

**3. Вывод**

Все это можно представить **довольно легко и быстро**, и никакие составители тестов не помешают вам сделать правильный выбор. Они-то работают только по правилам, а про интонационно-структурный анализ и не слышали никогда.

Что толку их ругать – у них своя задача (составить трудный тест), а у вас своя. **И это как бы поединок между ними и вами.** Экзамен есть экзамен, вы отвечаете за то, как освоили русский язык за 11 лет обучения. Просто заучивали правила или думали над их смыслом.

Comment: Sharon, я тоже раньше ставил ударение так: *плАто*, но переучился (все словари едины в этом вопросе: *платО*, слово французское). // Пункт 3. выбился из общего строя, или пусть 1. и 2. к нему присоединятся. :)

Comment: Спасибо, Александр за правку. Наш участник, вероятно, уже сдал экзамен и вряд ли еще сюда заглянет, так что рассчитывать на его благодарность не приходится.  А вот платО меня расстроило, не нравится мне французский вариант. И еще интересно, кто меня научил говорить неправильно. В отместку я нашла в словаре термин плАта (микросхема, панель). Основа у слова греческого происхождения, plate (англ) – плоский, почему мы должны говорить по-французски?

Comment: И дело здесь даже не во французском языке, а в том, что слово так и не вписалось в русскую лексику, осталось иноязычным. А ведь у него вроде бы много родственных слов -  платок, платье, платформа, платан и др. Вот и переучивают нас уже полвека. У Аванесова в словаре - (непр!) (1987 год).